# Is there a shortcut key or addon to refresh a linked object?

Tags: linked-data

I am on blender 2.93.0
Is there a shortcut key to refresh a linked object/collection?

Or even better, is there an addon that will enable auto refresh of linked data(objects/mats/collects etc)?

Comment: I don't know if it exists but you could simply File > Revert the file? You can right click on it to create a shortcut

Answer (score 1):

choose "blender file" in the outliner

[image]

right click on your linked file

[image]

click on reload

[image]

> Hint: you can add it to Quickfavorites so you can easily access it.

[image]